# Json.net Deserialization Where properties may not exist

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON object that may or may not have items with certain attributes.

Here's an example, someone can have none or many phone numbers.

```
 "PhoneNumbers": [
  {
    "PhoneId": 190434,
    "PhoneNumber": "213-555-0001",
    "PhoneExtension": null,
    "PhoneType": {
      "@odata.type": "#Enterprise.Contracts.DataContracts.Party.PhoneType",
      "PhoneTypeId": 18,
      "PhoneTypeAbbreviation": null,
      "PhoneTypeCode": "MOBILE",
      "PhoneTypeName": "MOBILE PHONE",
      "PhoneTypeDescription": "MOBILE PHONE"
    }
  },
  {
    "PhoneId": 190436,
    "PhoneNumber": "213-555-0003",
    "PhoneExtension": null,
    "PhoneType": {
      "@odata.type": "#Enterprise.Contracts.DataContracts.Party.PhoneType",
      "PhoneTypeId": 16,
      "PhoneTypeAbbreviation": null,
      "PhoneTypeCode": "FAX",
      "PhoneTypeName": "FACSIMILE",
      "PhoneTypeDescription": "FACSIMILE"
    }
  },
  {
    "PhoneId": 190437,
    "PhoneNumber": "213-555-0004",
    "PhoneExtension": 50004,
    "PhoneType": {
      "@odata.type": "#Enterprise.Contracts.DataContracts.Party.PhoneType",
      "PhoneTypeId": 14,
      "PhoneTypeAbbreviation": null,
      "PhoneTypeCode": "OFFICE",
      "PhoneTypeName": "OFFICE PHONE",
      "PhoneTypeDescription": "OFFICE PHONE"
    }
  }
],
```

Some people instead of having a MOBILE PHONE may have a BLACKBERRY, and vise-versa. They could even have both. Here's how I'm trying to get those attributes.

```
if (item.PhoneNumbers != null)
{
    Output0Buffer.OfficePhone = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "OFFICE").FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber;
    Output0Buffer.MobilePhone = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "MOBILE").FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber;
    Output0Buffer.BlackBerry = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "BLKBRRY").FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber;
    Output0Buffer.Fax = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "FAX").FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber;
    Output0Buffer.Extension = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "OFFICE").FirstOrDefault().PhoneExtension.ToString();
}
```

The problem I'm having is if someone doesn't have a Blackberry or they don't have a `MOBILE PHONE`, etc. I'm getting a null value exception.

I have my serializer settings to ignore null values, but I still seem to get the exception.

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;   
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ODataResponse>(json,settings);
```

Any thoughts on how I can change that LINQ where clause to support this?

EDIT: This method here seems to work. I didn't know if there was a better way of handling this so I didn't have to wrap it around every attribute

```
if (item.PhoneNumbers != null)
{
    string officePhone = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "OFFICE").Select(s => s.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefault();
    if (officePhone != null)
        Output0Buffer.OfficePhone = officePhone;
    string mobilePhone = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "MOBILE").Select(s => s.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefault();
    if (mobilePhone != null)
        Output0Buffer.MobilePhone = mobilePhone;
    string blackBerry = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "BLKBRRY").Select(s => s.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefault();
    if (blackBerry != null)
        Output0Buffer.BlackBerry = blackBerry;
    string fax = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "FAX").Select(s => s.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefault();
    if (fax != null)
        Output0Buffer.Fax = fax;
    string extension = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "OFFICE").Select(s => s.PhoneExtension).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
    if (extension != null)
        Output0Buffer.Extension = extension;

}
```

Comment: Put your ODataResponse class in Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if there is no item matching the `Where` clause.  So if you try to deference that return value directly, then of course you will get an exception when it is null.

Try using `Select` after the `Where` to project to the result you want *before* using `FirstOrDefault()`, e.g.:

```
Output0Buffer.BlackBerry = item.PhoneNumbers
    .Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "BLKBRRY")
    .Select(p => p.PhoneNumber)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `FirstOrDefault()` may return null, so `FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber` will throw an exception.

If you are using C# 4.6, you can do this (notice the `?`):

```
Output0Buffer.OfficePhone = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "OFFICE").FirstOrDefault()?.PhoneNumber;
```

Otherwise, you could do this instead:

```
    if (item.PhoneNumbers != null)
    {
        Output0Buffer.OfficePhone = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "OFFICE").Select(p => p.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefault();
        Output0Buffer.MobilePhone = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "MOBILE").Select(p => p.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefault();
        Output0Buffer.BlackBerry = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "BLKBRRY").Select(p => p.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefault();
        Output0Buffer.Fax = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "FAX").Select(p => p.PhoneNumber).FirstOrDefault();
        Output0Buffer.Extension = item.PhoneNumbers.Where(p => p.PhoneType.PhoneTypeCode == "OFFICE").Select(p => p.PhoneExtension).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this **WhereIf(bCondition, expression)** extention method to accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, bool condition, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (condition)
        return source.Where(predicate);
    else
        return source;
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, bool condition, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate)
{
    if (condition)
        return source.Where(predicate);
    else
        return source;
}
```

See this link for more information:

http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/ienumerable-t/whereif